# Get parent process id by Window Handle

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi

Is it possible to get process id based on it's child Window Handle in powershell?

For example, this script looking for Window Handle with titile "Warning":

```
$sig = @"
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr sClassName, String sAppName);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern uint GetLastError();
"@

$fw = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $sig -PassThru
$wname='Warning'

$find_window = $fw::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, $wname )
Write-Host $find_window
```

How it is shown in Task Manager:

```
 Program.exe
 |
  \Warning
```

Now i need to determine - what PID have this warning window. I know it is possible to implement in C# (which i don't use at all), but this should be done on powershell only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183.aspx). According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034669/505088), you can call that from PowerShell with this p/invoke:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
```

You supply a window handle in the first argument. The process and thread IDs are returned in the second argument and return value, respectively.